# Replace ConcurrentHashMap with EnumMap

Tags: java

All the while, I am using `ConcurrentHashMap`, if I want to achieve the following.

1. Able to iterate the map without throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`, while another thread is modifying the map content.
2. Allow two modification, by two threads at the same time.

Sometime, I use `enum` as key, and from [EnumMap Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html), I realize,

> Iterators returned by the collection
>   views are weakly consistent: they will
>   never throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException and
>   they may or may not show the effects
>   of any modifications to the map that
>   occur while the iteration is in
>   progress.

Hence, is it safe for me to replace

```
Map<Country, String> map =  new ConcurrentHashMap<Country, String>();
```

with

```
Map<Country, String> map =  Collections.synchronizedMap(new EnumMap<Country, String>(Country.class));
```

I know there is no `putIfAbsent` in `EnumMap`, but that is OK for me at this moment as I do not require it.

Comment: Why do you want to change them?  A concurrentHashMap will be more performant, has better concurrency properties and more functionality.  EnumMap alone (unsynchronized) would make sense only if you need raw performance and weren't concerned about data consistency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it for two reasons:

1. Lack of synchronization may cause memory visibility effects (since iterators of `Collections.synchronizedMap` are not synchronized).
2. Contract of `Iterator` would be broken - you may get `NoSuchElementException` when calling `next()` after `hasNext()` returned `true`.

Comment: The latter is perhaps more of an issue than the former.

Comment: The former can cause the latter.